# Multiprocessing an array of strings efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, string, performance, multiprocessing

I have an array of strings that I need to process. As the strings can be processed independently, I am doing this in parallel:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    ls = ["this", "is"]
    return [i.upper() for i in x.split(' ') if i not in ls]

arr = np.asarray(["this is a test", "this is not a test", "see my good example"])
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
tst = pool.map(func, arr)
pool.close()
```

My question is the following: Are there any obvious ways that I can improve my code in terms of reducing memory-usage and CPU-time? Such as

- Using numpy-arrays in `func`?
- Using Python-lists instead of numpy-arrays?
- ...?

Comment: Why are you using numpy arrays?

Comment: @roganjosh I was under the impression that is preferred over Python-lists as they are more efficient (I'm probably wrong on this one then..?)

Comment: Yep :) Numpy arrays are in no way inherently more efficient than lists. In lots of cases (e.g. appending in a loop) they are slower. They only really work when you use numpy methods on them; then they can outstrip list operations by orders of magnitude. But not everything can be done with an array

Comment: if `ls` is actually quite large in your real problem, the first thing you want to try is to convert it to a `set`

Comment: @roganjosh It is +100 words, so that is definitely something I will do. `arr` is also very long, more than 1 million long.

Comment: Since you say,  `As the strings can be processed independently, I am doing this in parallel:`, look into `joblib` library

Comment: @kmario23 Will that be more efficient than `multiprocessing`?

Comment: `Joblib` is built on top of `multiprocessing` but it also supports multiple threads. I'd recommend a nice tutorial on: [Parallel processing in Python](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jmschr/lectures/Parallel_Processing_in_Python.html); In general, if the problem is embarassingly parallel **and** the dataset size is huge enough, then you'd gain a lot of improvement; Otherwise, it would be slower than doing it sequentially

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy [frompyfunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) to vectorize the entire execution. This is much faster than the native Python implementation.

```
import numpy as np
import functools


def func(x):    
    ls = ["this", "is"]
    print( [i.upper() for i in x.split(',') if i not in ls])


x = np.array(["this is a test", "this is not a test", "see my good example"])
np.frompyfunc(func,1,1)(x)
```

Comment: Will it be faster than parallelizing using `Joblib` or `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Thats what the documentation says that vectorization is faster than the normal implementation and numpy vectorize is wrapper of the original function frompyfunc()